# Pandas read mis-spaced columns

Tags: python, pandas

In the dataframe below, the separator for most columns are spaces. However, in the first column, the spaces are missing, causing all the columns to be shifted by one to the right. Is there a way to read in the dataframe so that I do not have to constantly select one column to the left to get to the column I need.

```
 RUN   YR    A     B       C        D        E       F 
    11988    8.98  173.90  210.81   19.54    0.69    0.00
    11989    7.00  317.30  280.06    1.82    2.10    0.00
    11990    8.82  237.00  275.55    0.77    1.20    0.00
    11991    8.39  408.90  402.21    0.00    2.50    0.00
    11992    8.48  291.20  285.01    0.00    1.67    0.00
    11993    5.90  437.40  419.76    2.86    3.39    0.00
    11994    7.65  405.30  346.13    5.69    2.96    0.00
    11995    7.06  352.80  383.85    0.07    2.17   16.05
    11996    5.14  377.10  339.10   13.55    2.27    0.00
    11997    6.80  350.20  383.68    7.32    2.82    0.00
    11998    8.21  462.80  358.38    2.85    3.40    0.00
    11999    8.70  322.30  387.90    2.89    2.67   24.64
    12000    8.33  297.40  233.06    0.00    1.75    0.00
```

Comment: Are you talking about the `0,1,2` column? That is just the index. This is your dataframe that is already imported, not a file, right? Can you be more specific about what you mean by spaces missing and "first column"?

Comment: Thanks beroe, the 0,1,2 column is indeed the index. The column under RUN has values like 11988 which should actually be 1 1988 (where 1988 is the year).

Comment: Can you then show exactly what is in your file? (and not the wrong pandas output)

Comment: Edited to show the original data now....

Comment: So, the RUN column has all values as 1, the year column should have the values 1988, 1989....2000

Comment: Do you also want to recover the correct first column? Or does it not matter that the first column is not correct as long as the column names of the other columns are correct?

Comment: I do not care about the first column. The other columns do matter though

Comment: Then my answer still stands. I will update it.

Comment: For posterity, it would be useful to show how to skip or split the first column, which is implied in the question. Others might not understand that the OP does not care that the first column is not actually split as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you show above is your file, you can use [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) (to read tables of *fixed-width formatted* lines) to read this in:

```
In [116]: s=""" RUN   YR    A     B       C        D        E       F 
     ...:     11988    8.98  173.90  210.81   19.54    0.69    0.00
     ...:     11989    7.00  317.30  280.06    1.82    2.10    0.00
     ...:     11990    8.82  237.00  275.55    0.77    1.20    0.00
     ...:     11991    8.39  408.90  402.21    0.00    2.50    0.00
     ...:     11992    8.48  291.20  285.01    0.00    1.67    0.00
     ...:     11993    5.90  437.40  419.76    2.86    3.39    0.00
     ...:     11994    7.65  405.30  346.13    5.69    2.96    0.00
     ...:     11995    7.06  352.80  383.85    0.07    2.17   16.05
     ...:     11996    5.14  377.10  339.10   13.55    2.27    0.00
     ...:     11997    6.80  350.20  383.68    7.32    2.82    0.00
     ...:     11998    8.21  462.80  358.38    2.85    3.40    0.00
     ...:     11999    8.70  322.30  387.90    2.89    2.67   24.64
     ...:     12000    8.33  297.40  233.06    0.00    1.75    0.00"""

In [117]: pd.read_fwf(StringIO(s))
Out[117]: 
    RUN   YR     A      B       C      D     E      F
0      11988  8.98  173.9  210.81  19.54  0.69   0.00
1      11989  7.00  317.3  280.06   1.82  2.10   0.00
2      11990  8.82  237.0  275.55   0.77  1.20   0.00
3      11991  8.39  408.9  402.21   0.00  2.50   0.00
4      11992  8.48  291.2  285.01   0.00  1.67   0.00
5      11993  5.90  437.4  419.76   2.86  3.39   0.00
6      11994  7.65  405.3  346.13   5.69  2.96   0.00
7      11995  7.06  352.8  383.85   0.07  2.17  16.05
8      11996  5.14  377.1  339.10  13.55  2.27   0.00
9      11997  6.80  350.2  383.68   7.32  2.82   0.00
10     11998  8.21  462.8  358.38   2.85  3.40   0.00
11     11999  8.70  322.3  387.90   2.89  2.67  24.64
12     12000  8.33  297.4  233.06   0.00  1.75   0.00
```

Because of the misformatting, the first column with name `'RUN   YR'` will not be correct, but the other are.

Comment: Thanks joris, sorry I might not have been very clear, but the column with values 0, 1, 2... is the index that pandas added and not actually in the file.